# Filtering by id of ToManyField

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a resource that looks like this:

```
class CustomerResource(ModelResource):

    locations = fields.ToManyField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'location_set', null=True)
    current_location = fields.ToOneField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'current_location', null=True)
    default_location = fields.ToOneField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'default_location', null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'customers'
        validation = CleanedDataFormValidation(form_class=RegistrationForm)
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']
        authorization = Authorization()
        excludes =['is_superuser', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'password', 'last_login',]
        filtering = {
            'location': ('exact'),
        }
```

I want to query the API for a list of customers filtered by whether they have a certain location in their location field. An example url would look like this:

```
localhost/v1/customers/?location=1&format=json
```

Unfortunately, while Tastypie recognizes my current filtering scheme as valid, when I pass in the location parameter to the URL, it appears to do nothing. The endpoint returns a list of all customers. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to extend filtering to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Your ToManyField is called 'locations', not 'location'

Comment: When I try to put locations into the filtering dictionary, I get an error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'location_set' into field. Choices are: contact, contacts_created, current_location, date_joined, default_location, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, location, logentry, membership, password, serviceplan, user_permissions, username`. When I change the field name to locations, I run into the issues described above.

Comment: In that case change the field name in your CustomerResource from locations to location.

Comment: Actually, I got it backward. Changing the field like you just suggested gives me the location_set error I described above. Changing the name of the filter gives me the same behavior I described in the original post.

Comment: In any case, did you get them all matching, should work fine as long as everything's matching.  Or if it'

Comment: It should work if they're all matching.  Otherwise post your actual Model class, you might have something weird going on there.